# Encoding a 16 byte array with custom Base 32

Tags: encoding

I have a 16 byte array and I am going to encode it to a base 32 string representation using a custom implementation of characters available

The problem I might have is:

16 bytes of data is 128 bits and to check how many characters I will get from encoding the byte array to base 32 I do:

128 / 5 = 25.6

I have always been getting 26 characters from a 16 byte array but from the above calculation is this because 25.6 rounds up to 26? Will the number of characters from an encoding always be 26 or could it ever be 25?

Thanks

Comment: If you are doing it correctly, it will always be 26 characters, otherwise if you have a large unbroken string of them, how will you know which are smaller than 26?

Comment: When you say doing it correctly, do you mean if the encoding code for base 32 is correct? After encoding the 16  bytes it is padded with '======'  I am just showing the characters which are not equal signs. Is this ok to do?

Comment: Encoding and base changes is not cryptography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad the input to the block size. The block size of a Base 32 encoder is 5-bits but in order to remain byte-aligned you will want to process in multiples of 8 and the least common multiple is 40.

So now you have 128 bits of input to process in 40 bit blocks and it doesn't divide, so you'll have to round up and pad the final block with zero bits or some other constant. You will also have to signal to the decoder somehow the number of padding bits used so that it can remove them when decoding.

If you look at [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) Base-64 you will see that by processing the input in blocks of 3 the encoder is able to remain byte aligned and solves the padding problem using "=" control characters which signal the padding to the decoder.

So with 128 bits you will find that after encoding 3 blocks you have 8 bits left over and will have to insert 32 bits of padding to complete the final 40-bit block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am limited to wanting the least amount of characters. If I was to trim the padding after the encoding would this be ok? Or will it have other impacts when decoding from the string back to the byte array?

Comment: Yes, you have the option to round *down* instead of up, but then you will lose data.

Comment: I'm confused sorry... At present I do base 32 on a 16 byte array and get 26 characters followed by 6 = signs. What I then do is remove the 6 = signs and show the 26 characters. Then when decoding, I add back the 6 = signs and can then use the data as before. What is wrong with this?

Comment: OK it makes sense, if all you ever want to encode is 128-bit inputs. In this case the number of padding bits is a constant.